# Option for creating a template when sending an email (to specific gmail address) in gmail

Tags: email, templates, gmail, html-email

I publish myself as a personal teacher for students, and recently the number of the clients increased, and I think that a proper solution for me will be like that:
when a client sends me an email on **Gmail** (more correct, puts my gmail address on "send to" field), a template will show up and the client will choose from dropdowns details like: grade, subject, phone number etc.
and that will help me manage myself in a proper way.

I would like to know if that possibility even exists on gmail, and if it does, how do i operate it.

thanks for helping me.

Comment: so something like a customized contact form, like some big companies have on their web sites?

Comment: This site is for asking developer related questions. Try posting on SuperUser for stuff like this. http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I can think of is using Filters. Filters in Gmail will let you label incoming mail based on the sender, subject or more. These will then show the label in your inbox. You can then keep a Draft or spreadsheet of response templates. You can read up more on filters [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).